# Retrieve nested object with OneToMany/ManyToOne doctrine relationship

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to do a one to many / many to one relationship between two DAO.

After annoting properties, I have an unexpected and unlimited object in the result.

```
/**
 * TicketSponsorDAO
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="ticket_sponsor")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class TicketSponsorDAO {
  /**
   * @var int
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="ticket_id", type="integer")
   */
  private $ticketId;

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TicketDAO", inversedBy="sponsors")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ticket_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
  private $ticket;

  ...
}
```

And

```
/**
 * TicketDAO
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="ticket")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class TicketDAO
{ 
  /**
   * @var int
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
  private $id;

  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="TicketSponsorDAO", mappedBy="ticket")
   */
  private $sponsors;

  public function __construct() {
      $this->sponsors = new ArrayCollection();
  }
  ...
 }
```

When I execute:

```
$sponsorEm = $em->getRepository(TicketDAO::class);
$spo = $sponsorEm->find("2");
var_dump($spo);
```

I have good properties about the ticket DAO, but the relation doesn't work and I have an unlimited object which is returned.

So in the MySQL database, I have the foreign key, the FK index and the primary key which are here.

The var_dump:
[image]

I follow this documentation: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional

Comment: Can you try it with dump from symfony? You may be in a circular reference

Comment: @albert you are right I have a recursion when I display sponsors from ticket that's var_dump not manage. With dump is ok

Comment: I've add it as an answer so you can mark it as close. I extremely recommend to get an IDE and learn to use a debugger.

Comment: I use Intellij IDEA the ultimate version... So I think it's not my IDE! It's just a bad side effect which is not mentioned in the doctrine documentation

Comment: If you use PHPStorm debugging you will not have issues with circular refernces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a recursion between the objets it's logic with OneToMany/ManyToOne relationship because the object of One is referred in the object of Many, ...

The var_dump doesn't manage it correctly.

To display the object I use `dump` from Symfony and it's good!

We can add a `__toString` with `return serialize($this)` into DAO class if the dump is displayed in browser.

Otherwise, we have an error:

> ... ENTITY could not be converted to string ...

Answer (score 2):

Use symfony dumper as you are having a circular reference.

```
dump($spo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi var_dump() will return your the type of objects and classes.

you should try to fetch the propertes like this

```
$spo->getSponsers();
```

it will return you an array or may be an collection;

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like one ticket have many sponsors and in this case I see only one problem. There is no auto_increment `id` in the `TicketSponsorDao` table, but there is a `ticket_id` column and I don't understand the purpose of that.

```
/**
 * TicketSponsorDAO
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="ticket_sponsor")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class TicketSponsorDAO {
  /**
   * @var int
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
  private $id;

  ...
}
```

Comment: Check my auto answer. The problem here it's the var_dump doesn't manage correctly the recursion of the relationship OneToMany/ManyToOne